# How to preserve an external Transaction id as the externalId for a linearState and get back the same using subscription

Tags: corda

I would like to  implement the following scenario using linearStates .

CoreBanking System-----Corda(Party A)---CordaNode (Party B)----ERP system

Corebanking system geneartes a transaction ID  and this transaction ID needs to be preserved for future contracts end to end .I would like to use this transaction id for linearstateID .

Query 1 : How can one deterministically construct a lineraId from and external Identifier . So that I can use this to query the valut later

Query 2 : How can I extract this from the client side  in scenarios given below

```
    updates.toBlocking().subscribe { update ->
        update.produced.forEach {
            logState(it)
        }
```

Query 3 : How can the application know and retrieve the linearid for a state  , once it is created .

Could you please point me to an example which uses an externalId as linear stateID  and the parties , uses this externalId for taking actions in a flow .

Answer (score 1):

**Query1:**
linearId is of the type UniqueIdentifier. If you take a look at the UniqueIdentifier class, you'll see that it can be bound to any existing external Id by passing in an external Id to the constructor.

Equality and comparison are based on the unique Id only, but you can simply refer to externalId within linearId i.e. linearState.linearId.externalId when querying the vault

**Query2**
Take a look at the [Vault API](https://www.corda.net/support/technical-office-hours/) docs, they're pretty comprehensive.

**Query3**
a linearState is typically defined as "A state that evolves by superseding itself, all of which share the common linearId." 
Given this, it's not so much about how Corda knows and retrieves the linearId for a state, but more like - given a particular state, I can use the linearId to look up previous versions of the state.

With your particular case, since you're providing an external Id, your other applications will able to determine which id and consequently which state maps to a particular e.g. account/trade.

We don't have a sample CorDapp that uses external Id just yet, but we'll look into creating one.

You're welcome to discuss this further during our [live streams](https://www.corda.net/support/technical-office-hours/) on Wednesdays

**Additional**

When you create the Initiator flow, you can provide it with properties e.g.

> object InvoiceFlow {
>
> ```
> @InitiatingFlow
> @StartableByRPC
> class Initiator(val externalId: String) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
> ```

Given your flow has now been passed the externalId, you can then query the vault to retrieve the relevant state, like so:

> val invoiceState =
>   serviceHub.vaultService.unconsumedStates().singleOrNull {
>   it.state.data.linearId.externalId == externalId }

or

> val invoiceState =
>   serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy().states.singleOrNull { it.
>   state.data.linearId.externalId == externalId }

You could then call this flow like this:

> services.startFlow(InvoiceFlow.Initiator(externalId
>   ))

Comment: Thank you . Is it possible to get the externalId when I get a  subscription notification  from "updates.toBlocking().subscribe"

Comment: Yes, within the lambda, you can refer to it.state.data.linearId.externalId

Comment: Now I got the way to map the state to externalid at receiver side .I request for  one more information . This is related to starting a flow using externalID . Because corebanking system or ERP will have only externalID and they dont know about the linearid  .Could you please give me sample about ,how could we start the flow from an RPC client with externalID as a linear state reference .

Comment: Thank you .It is provides insights to think in corda way.